# How to correctly use an object type in an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have this type definition:

```
Create Type "T1" as Table of Varchar2(10);/
```

This got executed.

How to use the T1 type variable in PL/SQL?. I have the following procedure:

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE P1
AS
  P_K   T1;
BEGIN
  SELECT P_K_J INTO P_K FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE NAME='JONES' ;
  FOR I IN P_K.FIRST..P_K.LAST LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE VALUES OF P_K ARE' || P_K(I));
  END LOOP;
END P1;
```

This gives the following error:

```
ERROR:
3/5      PL/SQL: Item ignored
3/5      PLS-00311: the declaration of "T1" is incomplete or malformed
```

My question is: how to instantiate a variable of type `T1`

Comment: Is `T1` and `P1` created in the same schema?

Comment: It's OK if you write PL/SQL code in capital letters, but it doesn't seem very friendly if you do the same thing with your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create Type "T1" as Table of Varchar2(10);
/
Create or replace PROCEDURE P1
AS
  P_K   T1;
BEGIN

  SELECT P_K_J BULK COLLECT INTO P_K FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE NAME='JONES';

  FOR I IN P_K.FIRST..P_K.LAST LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE VALUES OF P_K ARE' || P_K(I));
  END LOOP;

END P1;
/
```